# How to import excel into Cplex if not all the cells in excel matrix are filled with number?

Tags: cplex

The questions before are neither about filling cells or about reading a certain cell.

Already tried to key in excel data into "data" sheet of Cplex, but we require really big scope of data so manually key in will not be possible.

B from SheetRead(sheet,"'Original+B+R+S'!J2:O41");

Error shows that cannot read the matrix from excel sheet. We are thinking whether it's because some cells in excel are empty and some are with numbers. Really thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't process the data beforehand so that it imports cleanly? That is, you could write a script or a program to process your data, remove the empty cells or fill them in with reasonable default values, and then import the clean data into CPLEX. That may be the more reasonable solution here.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. The original question we'd like to solve is about routing. We'd like Cplex to know the predecessor trips for each trip index from excel. So each trip index has different numbers of predecessor trips, and that makes the matrix rows in excel not sharing same length. I tried fill in those empty cells with number "0", but Cplex still fail and I think it's because Cplex doesn't recognize "trip 0". But if I remove empty cells, that means I also remove some trips, which won't meet our question. Please help if you know any possible solution, really appreciate!

Comment: I think what you may want to use is a tuple. Assume you have a tuple with two fields: `tripindex` and `predindex`. Then you can store your data in two columns in Excel: for each trip index you add a new row for each of the predecessor trips. With that you can easily get all the data into OPL. Then you can massage this data inside OPL.

Another option would be to make all rows the same length by padding with invalid values (such as -1, for example). Then in your model just ignore any elements that correspond to invalid values.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback. I'll try the methods. Thank a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Turning my comment into an answer:

In case you have sparse data in Excel you have two options:

1. You can mark non-existent values with a special marker value, for example infinity or something very big/small. Sometimes even 0 (zero) can serve as a marker.
2. You can use tuples in OPL. This way you only have to specify the list of elements that are non-zero. This is usually much more compact and saves quite some memory. Take a look at the chapter about sparse data in the online user manual.